# How do I create a "macro" for regressors in R?

Tags: r, stata, substitution, lm, stata-macros

For long and repeating models I want to create a "macro" (so called in Stata and there accomplished with `global var1 var2 ...`) which contains the *regressors* of the model formula.

For example from

```
library(car)
lm(income ~ education + prestige, data = Duncan)
```

I want something like:

```
regressors <- c("education", "prestige")
lm(income ~ @regressors, data = Duncan)
```

I could find is [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28485069/6574038). But my application on the regressors won't work:

```
reg = lm(income ~ bquote(y ~ .(regressors)), data = Duncan)
```

as it throws me:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ bquote(.y ~ (regressors)), data =
Duncan,  :  invalid type (language) for variable 'bquote(.y ~ (regressors))'
```

Even the accepted answer of same question:

```
lm(formula(paste('var ~ ', regressors)), data = Duncan)
```

strikes and shows me:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula(paste("var ~ ", regressors)),
: object is not a matrix`.
```

And of course I tried `as.matrix(regressors)` :)

So, what else can I do?

Comment: Just use the other answer at that question. I'm not sure how easy bquote is going to be to adapt to a variable number of covariates.

Comment: @joran: Did not work either, I stated the error message in my question which I also made a bit more reproducible now.

Comment: Several demonstrations below of how the answer I referred to works. Don't give up so easily! ;)

Comment: @joran I'm hanging on!

Comment: BTW since we shouldn't call it "macro" how do we call it in R?

Comment: FWIW, using a `global` like this to hold variable names is widely deprecated as bad style in the Stata community. There are many better ways to pass lists of names between programs or commands or other code chunks on need to know basis.

Comment: jaySf: *"list of (string) names of regressors"*, I expect. You generally wouldn't need it to be global, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some alternatives. No packages are used in the first 3.

**1) reformulate**

```
fo <- reformulate(regressors, response = "income")
lm(fo, Duncan)
```

or you may wish to write the last line as this so that the formula that is shown in the output looks nicer:

```
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(Duncan)))
```

in which case the Call: line of the output appears as expected, namely:

```
Call:
lm(formula = income ~ education + prestige, data = Duncan)
```

**2) lm(dataframe)**

```
lm( Duncan[c("income", regressors)] )
```

The Call: line of the output look like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Duncan[c("income", regressors)])
```

but we can make it look exactly as in the `do.call` solution in (1) with this code:

```
fo <- formula(model.frame(income ~., Duncan[c("income", regressors)]))
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(Duncan)))
```

**3) dot**

An alternative similar to that suggested by @jenesaisquoi in the comments is:

```
lm(income ~., Duncan[c("income", regressors)])
```

The approach discussed in (2) to the Call: output also works here.

**4) fn$**  Prefacing a function with fn$ enables string interpolation in its arguments.  This solution is nearly identical to the desired syntax shown in the question using $ in place of @ to perform substitution and the flexible substitution could readily extend to more complex scenarios.  The `quote(Duncan)` in the code could be written as just `Duncan` and it will still run but the Call: shown in the `lm` output will look better if you use `quote(Duncan)`.

```
library(gsubfn)

rhs <- paste(regressors, collapse = "+")
fn$lm("income ~ $rhs", quote(Duncan))
```

The Call: line looks almost identical to the `do.call` solutions above -- only spacing and quotes differ:

```
Call:
lm(formula = "income ~ education+prestige", data = Duncan)
```

If you wanted it absolutely the same then:

```
fo <- fn$formula("income ~ $rhs")
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(Duncan)))
```

Comment: Due to the clearest `Call:` output your number one is mine. Likely the other solutions could be improved too in some way.

Comment: I have added info on the Call: output for all solutions.

Answer (score 8):

For the scenario you described, where `regressors` is in the global environment, you could use:

```
lm(as.formula(paste("income~", paste(regressors, collapse="+"))), data = 
Duncan)
```

Alternatively, you could use a function:

```
modincome <- function(regressors){
    lm(as.formula(paste("income~", paste(regressors, collapse="+"))), data = 
Duncan)  
}

modincome(c("education", "prestige"))
```