# How to properly address covariates in functions with their names listed into strings?

Tags: r, nse

I have a long list of covariates that I want to store as a string in order to work with it more conveniently in several functions.

I think the issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46615693/6574038), but I can't apply it to cases different to regression formulas.

```
xvar <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")

with(iris, iris[order(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, 
                      Petal.Length, Petal.Width), ])  # working

with(iris, iris[order(xvar), ])  # not working
```

Or an other case

```
with(iris, ave(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, 
           Petal.Length, Petal.Width))  # working

with(iris, ave(xvar))  # not working
with(iris, ave(noquote(paste(xvar, collapse = ", "))))  # not working as well
```

Especially the paste-version I don't understand why it's not working, though it yields exactly the same string as the one in the parentheses:

```
> noquote(paste(xvar, collapse = ", "))
[1] Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that character values and actual code are very different. Just compare

```
 with(iris, order("Sepal.Length"))
 with(iris, order(Sepal.Length))
```

Functions like `paste()` only make strings and `noquote()` also just returns strings, it just doesn't print the quotes. If you are trying to dynamically create code, you are generally going to have to parse string into proper R language objects. Sometimes you can do some sneaky alternatives.

One possible work around is to use `do.call` to pass the columns that you want to sort by as separate parameters to `order`. You can do

```
iris[do.call("order", iris[xvar]), ]
```

the `dplyr` package has tidyevels methods to also help with stuff

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% arrange(!!!rlang::syms(xvar))
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative explanation. Since you're talking about this as a work around, can I assume there is no real method? E.g. the `iris[do.call(.), ]` seems not to be adaptable for `ave()`.