# Call variables for regression in lmer function

Tags: r, string, lme4

I am calling the `lmer` function from the `lme4` package. The function works if I hard code the column names. If I refer to it as a variable, though, it throws an error. My ultimate goal is to call a string that includes '+' between each column name.

Here is an example `lmer` call:

```
colnames(df)
COL_A, COL_B, COL_D
```

This works:

```
output <- lmer(COL_A ~ 1 + COL_B + 1|COL_D, df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

This does not:

```
var_a <- COL_A
var_b <- COL_B
var_c <- COL_D

output <- lmer(var_a ~ 1 + var_b + 1|var_c, df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

Error that comes up:

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'var_b')
```

If this can be figured out it would be awesome.

My ultimate goal though is to call the function as a string, so something like this:

```
form_lmer<-"COL_A ~ 1 + COL_B + 1|COL_D"

output <- lmer(form_lmer, df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

Has anyone encountered this sort of thing before?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616150/6574038) help?

Comment: `output <- lmer(as.formula(form_lmer), df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)`?

Comment: Did you mean `var_a <- "COL_B"` or `var_a <- df$COL_B` or something else? `var_a <- COL_B` will only work if there's already a `COL_B` variable living in your global environment ...

Comment: By the way, your final specification (in terms of `form_lmer`) does actually work, although I wouldn't recommend it ...

Comment: @BenBolker why ?

Comment: it's a little bit safer to make the formula an actual formula, which has an appropriate environment associated with it. There's a small chance that something weird could happen downstream. (I think we've fixed most of those edge cases, but I'm never 100% sure ...)

Comment: @Tung can you please put yours as an answer? That worked great.

Comment: Actually @Tung, I'm getting an error in the last part for 1|COL_D in the formula

Comment: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:50: unexpected numeric constant

Comment: @nak5120: can you share your data using `dput()` so folks can actually test

Comment: nevermind figured out the issue, dumb mistake. Can you put that as an answer please the: `output <- lmer(as.formula(form_lmer), df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
output<-lmer(paste0(var_a, "~ 1 + ",var_b," + 1|",var_c), df, REML = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: I would recommend `form <- reformulate(c(var_b,sprintf("(1|%s)",var_c)),response=var_a)`; not particularly different, but maybe a little more elegant.