# How to use vars in lm in an own function?

Tags: r

I want to write a function, which calculates a linear regression based on the input.

I can build the function, but when I call it (e.g. `myregression(i1,i2)` it will result in an error)

```
myregression <- function(input1, input2) {
   model <- lm(data = trainData, example ~ input1 + input2)
}
```

How can I use the input in the function `lm`?

Comment: You may need `paste0("example ~",  input1, " + ", input2)` and use `myregression("i1", "i2")`

Comment: Another approach assuming that `input1` and `input2` are character strings giving the names of columns in `trainData` is `lm(trainData[c("example", input1, input2)])` .

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46615693/6574038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, we can use `paste` to create the formula

```
myregression <- function(input1, input2) {
    model <- lm(data = trainData, paste0("example ~", input1, " + ", input2))
     }
```

---

Or another option is `reformulate`

```
myregression <- function(input1, input2) {
      model <- lm(data = trainData, reformulate(c(input1, input2), "example"))
  }
```

and call the function as

```
myregression("i1", "i2")
```